# How to get table from table contains list column of strings by sql or python

Tags: python, sql, list

I have table as following

```
eventID countries
aaffff. Japan, US, Frunce
aafggg. Japan, Frunce
```

i want to get new table

```
eventID countries
aaffff. Japan
aaffff. US
aaffff. Frunce
aafggg. Japan
aafggg. Frunce
```

As i dont know how much strings i will have in the column countries the function Split_part will not assist me. if there is better way to do it by python i will be glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [24]: a = [{"eventID":"aaffff","countries":"Japan, US, Frunce"},{"eventID":"aafggg","countries":"Japan, Frunce"}]

In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
  eventID          countries
0  aaffff  Japan, US, Frunce
1  aafggg      Japan, Frunce

In [28]: df["countries"] = df["countries"].str.split(",")

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
  eventID              countries
0  aaffff  [Japan,  US,  Frunce]
1  aafggg       [Japan,  Frunce]

In [30]: df.explode("countries")
Out[30]:
  eventID countries
0  aaffff     Japan
0  aaffff        US
0  aaffff    Frunce
1  aafggg     Japan
1  aafggg    Frunce
```

Comment: is there a way also to do it by sql?

Comment: I think you can insert the modified dataframe to the required database